# content type adds extra html

Tags: php, javascript, header, download

for the download forced, when I save the file it has some extra html test.
my code

```
<?php                                                                 
header('Content-type: text/plain');                              
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="abc.txt"'); 
echo "test";                                             
?>
```

when I save this is what I have

```
<script language="javascript">
// some garbage

//-->
</script>

test
```

I want only test.

Comment: Are you certain your server has not been compromised in any way?

Comment: Are you really sure that that is your whole PHP script?

Comment: Please show us "the garbage".

Comment: yes the javascript is in include file, so server is not compromised. I just need to exclude it from download part as that information is garbage

Comment: What include file?  Please show us your entire code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't include the include file.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of stating the obvious, something is already outputting some code/including a file, etc. before you're trying to set the headers.

Whilst the cause of this is likely to be specific to your web app (you'll need to check precisely what's being output from the ground up), the requirement is that the headers need to be the very first (before any HTML, etc.) things output.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, do you mean that the JavaScript being outputted is in the PHP file that's doing the outputting, and you want it to *not* output that?

The first thought would be to remove the JavaScript.  But beyond that, you may find some use from something like [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to capture your output buffer and manipulate it before sending it to the client.

Comment: exactly what I was going to say. strip out unneeded includes. but, if you can't you can always capture all the output you don't want, and discard it, save it, or whatever else you want to do that's not letting the user see it in the download.